# How to check condition in <td>

Tags: html, angular, angular6, angular2-forms

I want to check the condition if status is draft no need to show the date.so date field should be 'no date'; for other condition date should be there

i was trying with based on status but its no coming

```html
<td>{{notificationContentObj.status}}</td>
 <td>{{!notificationContentObj.status ? 'no' : notificationContentObj.createdon | date: 'MMM d, y HH:mm' }}</td>

<tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let notificationContentObj of notificationContentLists;let i = index">
            <td>{{notificationContentObj.contenttitle}}</td>
            <td>{{notificationContentObj.categoryid}}</td>
            <td>{{notificationContentObj.productid}}</td>
            <td>{{notificationContentObj.templatename}}</td>
            <td>{{notificationContentObj.contenttype}}</td>
            <!-- <td>{{notificationContentObj.isactive ? 'Active' : 'Archived'}}</td> -->
            <td>{{notificationContentObj.status}}</td>
            <td>{{!notificationContentObj.scheduledstatus ? 'NO' : 'YES'}}</td>
            <!-- <td>{{notificationContentObj.createdon | date: 'MMM d, y HH:mm' }}</td> -->
            <td>{{!notificationContentObj.status ? 'no' : notificationContentObj.createdon | date: 'MMM d, y HH:mm' }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I just need based on the status = 'DRAFT' date should be empty.

Comment: format the question well! n you can jst use `<td *ngIf="notificationContentObj.status === 'DRAFT'">`

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngIf` syntax instead of ternary operator.

```html
<td *ngIf="notificationContentObj.status === 'DRAFT'">
  no
</td>
<td *ngIf="notificationContentObj.status !== 'DRAFT'">
  {{notificationContentObj.createdon | date: 'MMM d, y HH:mm'}}
</td>
```

Comment: use `ngIf else` and `toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator, but be carefully to encosed by parenthesis the element piped

```
{{notificationContentObj.status === 'DRAFT'?
    (notificationContentObj.createdon | date: 'MMM d, y HH:mm'):
    'no date' }}
```